# Prove Weak convergence in $H$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let the sequence $(x_n)$ of points of the Hilbert space $H$ weakly coincide
to the point $x ∈ H$. Prove that for an arbitrary point $y ∈ H-\{x\}$ has

the place is uneven

$\lim_{n→∞}||x_n − x|| < \lim_{n→∞}||x_n − y|| $.

Help to decide?

Comment: The question is formulated unclearly. Do you mean $x_n\to x$ weakly implies $\liminf \|x_n-x\|<\liminf \|x_n-y\|$ for $y\neq x$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc.Yes of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing $x_n$ by $x_n-x$ and $y$ by $y-x$ we may assume that $x_n\to 0$ weakly and $y\neq 0.$  Then we need to show that
$$\liminf\|x_n\|<\liminf \|x_n-y\|,\quad y\neq 0\quad (*)$$
We have
$$\|x_n-y\|^2=\|x_n\|^2+\|y\|^2-2{\rm Re}\,\langle x_n,y\rangle$$
Taking $\liminf$ gives
$$\liminf\|x_n-y\|^2=\liminf\|x_n\|^2+\|y\|^2$$ which implies $(*).$ Still we can get an explicit lower bound of the difference. Let $c=\sup\|x_n\|.$ Then $$\liminf\|x_n-y\|-\liminf\|x_n\|\\ \ge {\|y\|^2\over 2c+\|y\| }$$